# link .AI file intp SVG < image > element using a local resource

Tags: xml, image, svg

I want to link ai file into svg file, Here is my code.

```
<image xlink:href="31218_1.ai" style="stroke: none; stroke-width: 1; stroke-dasharray: ; fill: 000000; opacity: 1;" transform="translate(-466 -390)" width="932" height="780"></image>
```

But while opening file into illustrator it is asking for the replacement, can't recognize, where I am doing wrong, The ai file is in the same dir where svg file lays

Comment: Just a note: Those styles wont be applied to the linked image. Anyway - what is the target environment for that SVG? A browser wont even be able to display that .ai file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the file `31218_1.ai` is actually an Adobe Illustrator file then you are out of luck.  You can't just link any old filetype into an SVG `<image>`.  SVG `<image>` elements will only work with the common bitmap forms (JPEG, GIF etc) and SVG files.

Export the file from Illustrator as an SVG, then link to that instead.